Is there a nice basis for a pair of linear maps?
By using splitting fields I know you can put a (single) matrix in upper triangular form. This gives in my opinion the cleanest proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
consider the following...
WRONG FACT: Given two $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ there is an invertible matrix $P$ (with entries in an extension of the base field) such that both $PAP^{-1}$ and $PBP^{-1}$ are upper triangular.
If this were true, one could obtain clean proofs that the trace of $AB$ is equal to the trace of $BA$, and also that the determinant is a homomorphism. Unfortunately, the above (I think) does not hold.
THE QUESTION: Can the wrong fact be modified by replacing "upper triangular" with some other nice form?
PS: The form need not be canonical, just a nice form which can serve as a substitute for the wrong fact above. The matrix $P$ is allowed to have entries in a larger field than the base field for $U$ and $V$. If the fact is actually true please correct me!

Regarding your wrong fact, if both are upper triangular, then $P^{-1}e_1$ would be an eigenvector for both. So it clearly does not hold in general.

Existence of eigenvectors holds if you allow to increase your field. For example, you can take the algebraic closure of the ground field. see the post scriptum.

The issue is simultaneous eigenvectors

I found that thinking using the wrong fact was productive, even though I knew (or felt that) it would be wrong. I guess what I want to know is if there is a nice simultaneous form over an algebraically closed field. I overlooked the fact that the characteristic polynomials need to have a root in common. I'm just asking out of curiosity. I know Kronecker investigated this problem, but I cannot find any sources.

You write $L, T \colon U \to V$ with presumably different spaces $U$ and $V$, but ask for one basis and one matrix $P$. Do you mean $L, T\colon V \to V$ or do you allow different bases for rows and columns? In the second case, there exists a reasonable normal form, but not in the first case.

Simultaneous eigenvectors do not imply that the characteristic polynomials have a root in common. Also Kronecker developed his normal form for matrix pencils and the natural transformation for these is not simultaneous similarity. Gantmacher treats this extensively in his book on linear algebra.

Thank you for the reference!

I wrote this a bit carelessly, perhaps an edit is in order. I mean operators $L,T:V\rightarrow V$. Stated in terms of matrices: if $A$ and $B$ are as above, with entries in a field $F$, what I seek is an invertible matrix $P$ with entries in some extension of $F$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ and $PBP^{-1}$ are sufficiently nice. I'm idle atm so its really about getting a good way to think about things, or if you want just mere curiosity.

If I understand correctly, your question is literally the defining exemplar of a "wild" (as opposed to "tame") classification problem.  See @mathphysicist's answer to When is a classification problem wild?.

Is anything "unclean" about the usual easy proof that ${\rm tr}(AB)={\rm tr}(BA)$? The approach suggested here reminds me of the proverbial sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Its just a computation with sums... Just not very insightful.

There is a nice pair of bases.
In the complex field:

There exist unitary $Q$ and $Z$ such that $QAZ$ and $QBZ$ are both upper triangular. This is known as the QZ (or Generalized Schur) decomposition.

Alternatively, there are unitary $Q$, $Z$ such that $QAZ^{-1}$ and $ZBQ^{-1}$ are upper triangular. This is known as (the two-matrix case of) the periodic Schur decomposition.


The latter allows you to prove that the trace of $AB$ is equal to the trace of $BA$ (EDIT: after thinking more about it, I am not sure about using it to prove that the fact that the determinant is a homomorphism).
This is well studied in numerical linear algebra for the complex field; I have never seen it done in other fields, but the proofs can be generalized, dropping the unitary requirement in fields where it does not make sense. A sketch of the proof of the existence of the periodic Schur decomposition in an arbitrary field is as follows: take an eigenvector $v$ of $AB$, which always exists in a suitable field extension. Set $w = Bv$, so that $\lambda v = Aw$. Choose matrices $Q,Z$ (you may take them unitary or orthogonal if that makes sense for your field) such that $v$ is a multiple of the first column of $Q$ and $w$ is a multiple of the first column of $Z$; then we have
$$
QAZ^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}* & *\\ 0 & A_2\end{bmatrix}, \quad ZBQ^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}* & *\\ 0 & B_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now proceed inductively and transform the trailing $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ principal submatrices $A_2, B_2$ into upper-triangular form.

To the extent that the words don't commute (which extent isn't completely clear to me, since "basis" seems to be meant informally), you mean a basis of pairs, not a pair of bases, right?

@LSpice In my mind, the columns of $Q$ are a basis, and the columns of $Z$ are another basis; in this sense this is "a pair of bases". The linear operator $A$ becomes triangular if one considers it with $Z$ as basis for its domain and $Q$ as basis for its codomain, and viceversa for $B$.

Re, I see.  I think that the question meant "basis of pairs" in the sense of "transversal for conjugacy classes of sets of pairs", i.e., a choice of nice representative for each such conjugacy class (although this requirement of having only one representative was then relaxed).  But of course you explain clearly what your answer means, even if it is possible that you are using the term differently (and closer to what I think of as its usual usage) than does the original question.

Great answer! To be clear, my motivation is pretty silly... I just want to see what is the better reason behind the formulae $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$ and $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A) \text{det}(B)$. Ideally the matrices $Q,Z$ in your notation would be equal, but this is a great step in the right direction for sure!
